# How to browse to file url in MS Web Developer Express - css file

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, ide

I'm new to asp.net I,m using the Web Developer Express IDE , I cant seem to find out how to browse to a file url in a css file for instance:

```
   background: url( how do i browse to the file from hear ?) no-repeat left top;
```

In netbeans you would click the ctrl + spacebar to find the file and insert the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working in WDE, you need to type those manually. It doesn't provide a url/file picker in the CSS editor (there is a color picker in the new version, though).